# making joomla search page search engine friendly

Tags: seo, joomla

I want to add some seo features to a joomla search component, such as meta and integrated title page. What should i hack in the file ? 
Thanks 
joomla verion 1.0.15

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest hacking directly at the Joomla! search module. this should `modules/mod_search.php` file and go from there to add your functionality. I'm not too familiar with the topics of SEO optimization.

Comment: SEO doesn't need "optimization" after it. [/pedantry]